# How to handle messages in telegram groupchat individually? (aiogram)

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, aiogram

I'm using the aiogram api to build a FSM bot that returns a custom image at the end with the data inputted by the user. However, I'm having a pretty annoying problem. When I add my bot to a groupchat, the bot will handle messages for everyone instead of the single user. Basically, I would like the bot to only consider messages from the users that actually start the bot. Right now, I also have an inline keyboard, which pops up for everyone in the groupchat and not just for the single user who started the bot. Is there a way to handle requests in the groupchat separately? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter messages inside handlers via attribute

> **message.chat.type**

it could be **'private'** for private dialogs or **'group'** or
private, group, supergroup, channel

You could find all methods and attributes aiogram.types.chat in [**Aiogram documentation**](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/_modules/aiogram/types/chat.html)

For example:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def example_func(message: types.Message):

    if message.chat.type == 'private':

        # you could add here private functions

    elif message.chat.type == 'group':

        # you could add here group functions
```

[**inline bots**](https://core.telegram.org/bots/inline) Should help too